# Access existing connection string in web.config to new .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to .NET Core Web API. I was able to create a .NET Core Web API using the documentation provided and help from the people here. Documentation shows a way to access the database by putting a connection string in the `appsettings.json` which includes the database credentials, even though I already add encrypt I was thinking that this might not be completely safe. Is there a way to access the connection string from my existing `web.config` in the new `appsettings.json`?

Comment: hi Ping, let me know if one of the answer below guided you to answer your question, if not you can ask for further help here

Answer (score 0):

You may use ASP.NET Core Secret Manager tool for development environment and for production, you may use Azure vault.